# R treats multidimensional array as one dimensional

Tags: r, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

R seems to treat multidimensional array as one single array.
Is there a way to loop through the array and keep the structure in it?

It seems that I couldn't only use for i in 1:length(...) either, I'll need to know the dimension of the array at all time as length just returns the total size.
Is c not the correct function to use here? Thanks.

```
components = array(c( c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                       c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 ,1, 0, 1),
                       c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0 ,0, 1, 0),
                       c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), dim=c(4,10) )
components
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1     1
[2,]    0    0    0    1    1    0    1    0    1     1
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    1     1
[4,]    0    0    1    1    1    0    0    1    1     1
for( component in components ){ print(component) }
[1] 1
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 1
[1] 0
[1] 1
[1] 0
[1] 1
[1] 0
[1] 1
[1] 0
[1] 1
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 1
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 1
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 1
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
> length(components)
[1] 40
```

Comment: try `dim(components)` to get the dimensions for a nested loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate along each dimension in its own loop. If you don't know the length of the dimensions, use `dim`

For example, suppose we just want to print each number one at a time to the console in an array format:

```r
components = array(c( c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                      c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 ,1, 0, 1),
                      c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0 ,0, 1, 0),
                      c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), dim=c(4,10) )

for(i in 1:dim(components)[1]) {
  for(j in 1:dim(components)[2]) {
    cat(components[i, j], " ")
  }
  cat("\n")
}
#> 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  
#> 0  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  
#> 0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  
#> 0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can process rows with a slight modification of your code:

```
for( component in seq(nrow(components)) ){ print(components[component, ]) }
```

If the output is a vector you can convert it back to the original matrix dimensions with

```
x <- print(c(components))
dim(x) <- dim(components)
```